# How to compare two database table fields in asp.net

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Need to compare two different table cells in asp net. one table contains results and  goes as follows

```
round id = 1 |
game1 = 25 |
game2 = 25 |
game2 = 10 |

round id = 2 |
game1 = 25 |
game2 = 0 |
game3 = 0 |

the user table goes as follows :

username = Mike |
round id = 2|
game1 = 25 |
game2 = 10 |
game3 = 0|
```

I want it so that if `roundid` in users table matches one in results table then compare the values of the games of that round. So, for round 2 if game1 matches game1 of `results : totalscore =+ 1;`
and if it doesnt match it does nothing and adds nothing ! at the end display the total score in a label or textbox  how to do this in asp.net?

Comment: i was messing around with sqldatasources @SagarPudi so really there was no code behind i just need to know a method and i can search code for that method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, regardless of how you organize your application in terms of design paradigm (MVC, MVP, MVVM, etc) you should *always* deal with *data* and *events* rather than UI elements. That is, the UI elements *show* the data, UI events *are bound to the dataset* via events, so that the UI elements simply reflect concretely what is going on in the abstract at the level of the dataset.

Second, your so-called "user" table is not a user table. It appears to be a combination of user and round, so maybe we should call it an `AppUserRound` table.

So, let's assume `IList<Result> results` contains your results, and `IList<AppUserRound> userRounds` contains your users' rounds. To *join* these tables to each other by `RoundID`, form a "join" table using Linq:

```
var query = from ur in userRounds
            join r in results on r.RoundID = ur.RoundID
            select new { ur.Usernqame, r.RoundID, r.Game1, r.Game2, r.Game3 };
```

Obviously your particular data structures may be different, but using this joined table, you can display a list that includes information from both tables.